# How to have a flavour without applicationIdSuffix?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, android-productflavors

I have a **released** application that I want to decline on several others with the flavour system.

I managed to setup the environment to match that system with the different folders. But when I want to give my first app **no** `applicationIdSuffix`, I have a build error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processAppDebugGoogleServices'.
>   No matching client found for package name 'com.package.name'

Is it even possible to have a flavour without an `applicationIdSuffix` ?

Here is my flavour section:

```
productFlavors {
        first {
            versionCode 6
            versionName "1.0.5"
        }
        second {
            applicationIdSuffix ".second"
            versionCode 4
            versionName "0.0.5"
        }
    }
```

Thanks a lot for any help you could provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it even possible to have a flavour without an **applicationIdSuffix**?

Sure it is possible.

Judging from a task that has failed (*processAppDebugGoogleServices*), I assume you have problems with **google-services.json**, which was generated for another package name. Generate a new one with an updated package name.